# Write a single byte at memory address

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I am trying to write a single byte from the register %cl into a memory address X where X = 0x7 + %ebx. I thought the following would work fine :

```
movl %esp,%ebx
movl (%ebx),%ebx
movb %cl,0x7(%ebx)
```

Although, for some reason, I get a SIGSEGV when executing this specific line and I am at a loss trying to make it work. The address I have stored in %ebx is located on the stack.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does `%ebx` contain at the point? In other words, how do you know that the memory location `0x7 + %ebx`  is writable?

Comment: %ebx contains an address pointing in the stack, this is why I believe this location is writable.

Comment: You're not running this as a 64-bit process, right?

Comment: It is definitely a 32-bit process. The value of %ebx when I am debugging with ddd is : 0x80483d0.

Comment: You know that `%ebp` and `%ebx` are different, right?

Comment: Right, sorry for the typo, I did mean %ebx.

Comment: Okay, now how do you know it's on the stack? Can you show us the code that sets `%ebx`?

Comment: Sure I am adding it into the code snippet from my original question.

Comment: What's the purpose of the second line in your code? You are moving whatever is on the stack at address `%ebx==%esp` into `%ebx` so in the third line there no longer is a valid stack address in `%ebx`!

Comment: The code I have shown are the first lines of a function call receiving a single parameter which is the address of a byte where I am supposed to write the result. Thus I am making my call this way :
`call MyFunction`
`.string "a"`

Comment: This just doesn't look right. If `%ebx` points to the current stack then that makes `mov %ebp,%ebx` somewhat redundant since it sets the stack pointer to `%ebx`. There's no code showing where `%ebx` comes from, so it's suspicious. Normal stack frame protocol would `mov %ebp,%esp` and then subtract off of `%esp` to establish variable space. Secondly, if you write to a stack, it's usually supposed to be pre-decrement, so `mov (%ebx),%ebx is also suspect. It would help if you provided more context.

Comment: Your comments helped me figure this out. My function is never meant to return which is why I am not using a regular prologue. Also the reason I was getting a SIGSEGV was because I was trying to test my function outside of its context, and the caller's code wasn't located on the stack as it should have been.